# queryResultMaxDocsCached and documentCache in solr

Tags: caching, solr

As I understand it, `queryChache` caches a list of matched documentIds for each query.
Based on the information provided in the book `Solr in Action`, we set the `queryResultMaxDocsCached` parameter to a value based on the maximum number of documents we want each query to cache. If that is true, does that value add to the amount we set in `documentCache` ? What is the difference between the two ?

Excerpted from `Solr in Action` for `queryResultMaxDocsCached`

> As you can imagine, a
>   result set holding millions of documents in the cache would greatly impact available
>   memory in Solr. The  element allows you to limit the
>   number of documents cached for each entry in the query result cache.

Excerpted from `Solr in Action` for `documentCache`

> The query result cache holds a list of internal document IDs that match a query, so even
>   if the query results are cached, Solr still needs to load the documents from disk to produce
>   search results. The document cache is used to store documents loaded from disk
>   in memory keyed by their internal document IDs. It follows that the query result cache
>   uses the document cache to find cached versions of documents in the cached result set.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the descriptions you've posted, the *queryCache* keeps the query mapped to the document ids for that query. i.e. a search for "foo" gave "these ids": `foo -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

The Document Cache simplifies the lookup of those document ids, meaning that Solr won't have to attempt to load them from disk again: `1 -> {'bar': 'foo', 'spam': 'eggs'}, 2 -> {'bar': 'foo', 'python': 'idle'}, 3 -> ...,` etc.

If you have a different query, but it still references the same set of (or a subset of) documents, those documents can be looked up in the cache instead of being read from disk: `bar -> [2, 8, 16]` would still be able to find document `2` in the cache, and avoid going to disk to load the details of the document.

These caches are separate, and handled by separate settings.

Comment: I think you missed my question. I want to know how are  queryResultMaxDocsCached and documentCache settings different and does the queryResultMaxDocsCached add to documentCache count ?

Comment: One is about the number of document ids cached in in the queryResult, the other is about the number of documents (actual documents and their contents) cached separately from all the caches. They're separate caches with separate settings, so the _total cache size_ inside Solr is (queryResultCacheSize + documentCache + filterCache + fieldCache + .. etc). These caches are as far as I know not related to each other in any way, except that they can use each other for required functionality.